# Error while opening SQLite database using OPEN_READWRITE flag

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to open a database situated at \mnt\sdcard but getting the following error.

> sqlite returned: error code = 8, msg = statement aborts at 37: [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
>   android_metadata (locale TEXT)] attempt to write a readonly database

below are the codes snippet

> String myPath = "\mnt\sdcard\myproject\mydb";
>
> sourceDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

it is working perfectly if I open the db using NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS flag.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to create a table? Does the  `CREATE_IF_NECESSARY` flag help?

Comment: I want to insert values to a table. Yes I tried CREATE_IF_NECESSARY too, but no help.

Comment: What permissions does your app request?